# How to rename a local Git branch from inside IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

There are plenty of things you can do with Git plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, but I haven't found a way to rename a branch. Is there one?

I know I can always bring up a terminal and do `git branch -m source target`, but I expected to find a GUI solution as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a couple of pending issues with this feature:

- [IDEA-89927](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89927): Renaming branches is not captured by IDEA
- [IDEA-131021](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131021): Add "Rename branch" action

The latter is not yet implemented.
The former does show the only way (mentioned by the OP) currently available:

> Go to the command line and execute `git branch -m <old_name> <new_name>`

But even that has refresh issue on IDEA.

---

Update January 2017: [IDEA-131021](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131021) might have been implemented, as illustrated by [Pavlo Zvarych](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648478/pavlo-zvarych)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41631547/6309). It is consistent with the [proposal](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131021#u=1473876457355):

> introduce menu item in `Git | Branches` popup for current branch and place the actions related to the current branch in its second-level submenu.

[image: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/image.png?file=74-343247&c=true&rw=526&rh=121&u=1473876457355]

Comment: Although [IDEA-89927](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89927) is not marked as fixed, I don't experience the "refresh" issue in 14.1.4, it updates the branch name in the corner immediately after I switch focus from my terminal to IDEA. But I don't use IDEA's terminal, I use xterm as an external tool.

Answer (score 5):

*VCS > Git > Branches...*

1. Click on the right arrow of your project (look at *Repositories*).
2. The sub-window with branches will appear. Click on the right arrow
   of the branch you want to rename.
3. Rename.

*If you want to rename a branch you currently on. You have to checkout to another branch and then to find your branch in a way described above and rename it.*

[image]

Comment: Renaming the branch you are currently working on is now also supported from within the branch. You no longer have to switch to another.