# Renaming current branch in intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In intellij I can rename git branches but there is no 'rename' when i click on the current branch. does intellij support it or again - console?

Answer (score 11):

First you can't rename the branch name if you are on it (As of ***IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2***) . So to change the `Branch` name on IntelliJ IDEA you need to switch to other branch.

**1. View list of branches**

[image]

I'm on master and I'm trying to rename branch test (I'm not on the branch that I want to rename)

**2.Select Branch you want to rename**

[image]

If you select the branch you can see a number of options, one of which is `Rename`

**3. Select Rename**

[image]

**4. Click ok and Branch will be `Renamed`**

[image]

**5. Recheck if branch name is changed**

[image]

Comment: In 2018 release there is this feature (though not in git log view). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901384/how-to-rename-a-local-git-branch-from-inside-intellij-idea